# How to get coredump file when an application kill itself?

Tags: process

On Centos 6.5, I have an application and when running it about 5 minutes, it stop with only a "Killed" on terminal, and I can not get core dump file. 
I already enable core dump file, by command "ulimit -c unlimited", specify the core file name, location and file  name format.
Can everybody help me why core dump file not generated when an application killed itself!
Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Can you show us the code where you set the core dump filename etc. ?

Comment: Firstly, set the core dump file size to unlimited by command 
 "ulimit -c unlimited".
Create folder to stored coredump file
 "mkdir /tmp/cores"
 "chmod 777 /tmp/cores".
Edit core file pattern by edit file “/etc/sysctl.conf“:

 "kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/cores/core.%e.%p.%h.%t"